# Converting Set to List Yields Unpredictable Number of Elements

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Terraform v0.13.7

- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v2.70.0 / v3.59.0
- provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0

Hi,

I'm trying to move from version 2.70.0 to version 3.X of the AWS provider plug-in. That entails dealing with a change in the **domain_validation_options** attribute of **aws_acm_certificate**, which becomes a set rather than a list.

I have code managing a certificate with 3 SANs in addition to the main certificate name. With version 2.70.0 of the AWS provider plug-in, as expected, this produces a four-element list, as can be seen in this output from a **terraform show -json planfile**:

```
                "domain_validation_options": [
                  {
                    "domain_name": "example.net",
                    "resource_record_name": "blah-1.example.net.",
                    "resource_record_type": "CNAME",
                    "resource_record_value": "blah-1.acm-validations.aws."
                  },
                  {
                    "domain_name": "*.a.example.net",
                    "resource_record_name": "blah-2.a.example.net.",
                    "resource_record_type": "CNAME",
                    "resource_record_value": "blah-2.acm-validations.aws."
                  },
                  {
                    "domain_name": "*.b.example.net",
                    "resource_record_name": "blah-3.b.example.net.",
                    "resource_record_type": "CNAME",
                    "resource_record_value": "blah-3.acm-validations.aws."
                  },
                  {
                    "domain_name": "*.c.example.net",
                    "resource_record_name": "blah-4.c.example.net.",
                    "resource_record_type": "CNAME",
                    "resource_record_value": "blah-4.acm-validations.aws."
                  }
                ],
```

Also as expected, I can address each one of these list elements by its index, e.g.:

`aws_acm_certificate.sslcert.domain_validation_options[0]`

When I install a 3.X version of the plug-in, however, a set is returned. I am trying to make things easy by converting it to a list with the tolist() function. That returns a lexicographically ordered list--which is expected.

```
                "domain_validation_options": [
                  {
                    "domain_name": "*.a.example.net",
                    "resource_record_name": "blah-2.a.example.net.",
                    "resource_record_type": "CNAME",
                    "resource_record_value": "blah-2.acm-validations.aws."
                  },
                  {
                    "domain_name": "*.b.example.net",
                    "resource_record_name": "blah-3.b.example.net.",
                    "resource_record_type": "CNAME",
                    "resource_record_value": "blah-3.acm-validations.aws."
                  },
                  {
                    "domain_name": "*.c.example.net",
                    "resource_record_name": "blah-4.c.example.net.",
                    "resource_record_type": "CNAME",
                    "resource_record_value": "blah-4.acm-validations.aws."
                  },
                 {
                    "domain_name": "example.net",
                    "resource_record_name": "blah-1.example.net.",
                    "resource_record_type": "CNAME",
                    "resource_record_value": "blah-1.acm-validations.aws."
                  },
                ],
```

What is unexpected is Terraform reports that it is a *two-element* rather than a four-element list. When I try to access what appears to be the last element in the second **terraform show -json planfile** output quoted above *("domain_name": "example.net")*, it gives me the following error:

```
  on common/certificate/certificate.tf line 14, in locals:
  14:   vopt = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.sslcert.domain_validation_options)[3]

aws_acm_certificate.sslcert.domain_validation_options is set of object with 2 elements
```

Can anyone help me understand why this is happening? And is there a more reliable way to inspect variables than browsing the output of **terraform show -json planfile**?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I probably should have shared the code that is generating my problem. Here is an anonymized version of it.

Calling module:

```
module "sslcert-example_net" {
  source = "./common/certificate"
  name   = "example.net"

  SAN = [
    "*.a.example.net",
    "*.b.example.net",
    "*.c.example.net",
  ]
}
```

Child module:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "sslcert" {
  domain_name = var.name

  subject_alternative_names = var.SAN

  validation_method = "DNS"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

locals {
  vopt = tolist(aws_acm_certificate.sslcert.domain_validation_options)[3]
}

resource "ns1_record" "dnsvalidation-sslcert" {
  depends_on = [aws_acm_certificate.sslcert]
  zone       = var.name

  domain = substr(
    local.vopt["resource_record_name"],
    0,
    length(local.vopt["resource_record_name"]) - 1,
  )
  type = "CNAME"

  answers {
    answer = local.vopt["resource_record_value"]
  }
}
```

Comment: A set is containing only unique values. Now certainly it is not really clear for me from the question why do you get 2 elements instead of 4, but you can use `terraform state show aws_acm_certificate.sslcert` to see content of `sslcert` resource.  Moreover, you can use the `terraform console` to be able to browse resources.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that produces the error?

Comment: Hi, Marcin. I added it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Ervin. I thought to use terraform console, but the issue resides in code in a child module and I can't seem to use terraform console to run expressions on variables in my child modules. It yaps that there's "no such variable" in my "root module".

Comment: Sorry, but your code does not match the error. The error writes that you are using `_options)[3]`, while the code is `_options)[0]`. Please make sure that your question factually represent your real issue. Also you have to ping @Marcin if you are replying in the comments to someone.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the heads up. You're right--in the code above, I had changed the index to 0 because I was trying different things. I'll update it to reflect 3. Basically, indices 0 and 1 work but indices 2 and 3 do not, in what appears to be a four-element list.

Comment: No problem. But the code, as given in the question, is correct. Your `local.vopt` should work as expected. Thus maybe your real code has some differences which are not reflected in the question?